# When using AVPlayerViewController can't display MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork during Airplay

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, airplay, mpnowplayinginfocenter

A section of my app displays various forms of media from an API, images, videos and songs (audio + an image). I'm using AVPlayerController and using an UIImageView on top of its `contentOverlayView` to display song album images. I am setting the nowPlayingInfo dictionary, something like this when the media starts playing:

```swift
private func setupNowPlaying() {
        
    let elapsedTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerController?.player?.currentTime() ?? CMTime(value: 0, timescale: CMTimeScale()))
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerController?.player?.currentItem?.duration ?? CMTime(value: 0, timescale: CMTimeScale()))
        
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
        MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: airPlayAlbum,
        MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1.0,
        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: airPlayName,
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: airPlayArtist,
        MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: elapsedTime,
        MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: duration,
        MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyMediaType: 1
    ]
        
    if let image = imageView?.image {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
            return image.resizedImage(size: size)
        }
    }
        
    setupCommands()
    hasSetupNowPlaying = true
}
```

This correctly displays everything in the iOS command centre for videos and songs. However when using the airplay button inside the AVPlayerViewController to cast to an external TV, it only displays the song title and a black screen with playback controls while the audio is playing, no album artwork. Videos display correctly

Following a recommendation online I tried setting:

```swift
playerController?.player?.allowsExternalPlayback = false
```

This hides the inbuilt airplay button on the playerController, but when using the command centre to trigger airplay, it now correctly displays album artwork, song title, album name etc on the external tv. With this setting on, videos no longer cast to the external tv, so thats not really a solution

Has anyone found a solution to leaving `allowsExternalPlayback` set to true, but also displaying the album artwork? There are lots of complaints online about this, but there seems to be no resolution

Comment: you should call setup for each play again, and do you use MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] _ in
            next() // your player next function
            return .success
        } and etc?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar `setupNowPlaying` is called after the content starts playing (using a observer on `playerController?.player?.rate`). Does it need to be called again? If so where/triggered by what? No i'm not using `nextTrack` there is currently no playlist style functionality, each media is played one at a time on different screens. When the user is done with one player, it is destroyed and a new one is created when they go to a different screen. Note that this issue happens 100% of the time, even if you only every play audio+ image and nothing else